# How to read gvfs file by TStream

Tags: freepascal

Linux feature is gvfs. I see TFileStream don't support gvfs files. So I need some other TStream object to read gvfs files. Do such streams exist?

Lazarus 1.7, fpc 3.0

gvfs exposed to system as files:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/ftp:host=ftp.scene.org/ls-lR
```

Comment: How is gvfs exposed to the system. Do you need to use the gvfs library? I'd be surprised if you couldn't just read files as any other file.

Comment: If these are just files what is stopping you reading them?

Answer (score 0):

If these are proper files to the Linux kernel, I don't see why Lazarus would fail.

To check what is exactly happening you might want to use  **strace** on a simplest as possible program.

The call that fails could give you a clue what is happening. (like e.g. permissions)